# DAX: Calculate Start Dates Based on Duration & Order

Tags: powerbi

I have a table that I am trying to convert into a gantt chart. This table contains the task order (sometimes the same for those in parallel), as well as a task duration (by quarter).

If I have a Project Start Date = 1/1/2020, how could I calculate the Start & End dates for each subsequent task?

Example,

```
Task A: Order = 1, Duration = 4 ---> Start = 1/1/2020, End = 1/1/2021
Task B: Order = 2, Duration = 1 ---> Start = 1/1/2021, End = 3/1/2021
Task C: Order = 3, Duration = 2 ---> Start = 3/1/2021, End = 9/1/2021
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the total duration elapsed using appropriate filter modifiers. Then you can use `EDATE` function to get the start and end dates from the project start date adding elapsed months.

Here is an example formula of start date in a calculated column.

```
StartDate =

VAR ProjectStartDate = Date ( 2020, 1, 1 )
VAR CurrentOrder = Tasks[Order]

-- Quarters passed since the project start date before the current task
VAR DurationElapsedBefore = CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Tasks[Duration] ),
    REMOVEFILTERS (),
    Tasks[Order] < CurrentOrder
)

-- Multiplying by 3 to turn quarters into months
RETURN EDATE ( ProjectStartDate, DurationElapsedBefore * 3 )
```

The formula for end date is just replacing `<` with `<=` inside `CALCULATE`.